# Android - to list and play videos, does the device need the Youtube app?

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I was trying to use the Android YouTube API, but when I ran the demo apps, it said I need the YoutubeApp on my device.

And I am not going to require my users to go download an extra app. So it seems pointless.

Is there a way to just pull the videos in a channel and let the user select one video and play it through youtube.com?

Answer (score 0):

See I am also working with youtube api

it clearly says the it requires the youtube Application